# Table not created rails 2.3.8 plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I am trying to create a plugin for a rails application(fedena) rails version is 2.3.8.

created a file 20140709100104_ultimo_theme.rb in db/migrate folder in my plugin directory.

But the table is not getting created at the time of installation of plugin.
I have checked as it enters into class but it is not entering in the function self.up,
Here is the file content.

```
class UltimoTheme < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    puts "creating table"
    create_table :ultimo_theme do |t|
      t.string   :theme_name
      t.boolean  :is_current
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
  def self.down
    drop_table :ultimo_theme
  end
end
```

As a newbie in rails do not getting any idea of it.

----------EDIT--------

Getting error while running

**rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20140709100104 --trace**

```
** Execute db:migrate:up
rake aborted!
No migration with version number 20140709100104
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/migration.rb:455:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/migration.rb:409:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/tasks/databases.rake:135:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate:up
```

Comment: Did you get any error when you run rake db:migrate?

Comment: What happens when you run `rake db:migrate` ?

Comment: Can you try running once with this command rake db:migrate:up VERSION=20140709100104

Comment: no error while running rake db:migrate

Comment: Try this command rake db:migrate:all or rake db:migrate:plugin NAME=pluginname

Comment: @Icicle these commands are not working

Answer (score 0):

Use this rake command

```
 rake fedena:plugins:install_all
```